# Null pointer exception error in the line (driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); unable to get the url after browser invoke

Tags: selenium

```
public class base {
public WebDriver driver;
public Properties prop;
public WebDriver intializeDriver() throws IOException

{

prop=new Properties();

FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("//Users//venkat//eclipse-workspace//E2EProject1//src//main//java//Academy1//data.properties");

prop.load(fis);

String browserName=prop.getProperty("browser");

if(browserName.equals("chrome"))

{
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/venkat/Downloads/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
}
else if(browserName.equals("Firefox"))
{
//Firefox code
}
else if(browserName.equals("IE"))
{
//IE code
}
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
return driver;
}
}
```

unable to get the url after browser invoke, showing null pointer exception error in the linedriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: Its probably because you have two WebDrivers. One its from here: public WebDriver driver; which is null => throwing that exception, and the other one WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); which is creating the chrome instance and its not null.  To fix it change the WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); into driver = new ChromeDriver();

Comment: yeah corrected and got the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your question. However, rather than a large code block with some secondary commentary, please walk the community through the problem rather than expecting interpretation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to run on Chrome and you are passing `browserName` with value of `Chrome` while you are checking it against equality to `chrome` value.
So you are not entering

```
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/venkat/Downloads/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
}
```

code block and also not entering other browsers drivers initialization blocks.
So `driver` remains not initialized.
So when you try to apply any  action on it - i.e. `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` it throws null pointer exception.

So, instead of `if(browserName.equals("chrome"))` you should use  `if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))`

Comment: tried with the suggestion but same error. browser invoke is fine i mean chrome browser is opening but url is not catching up !